# Copying Values from several columns into a different worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have one workbook that I need to copy data from columns I, K, and M on the first worksheet into column A of the last worksheet. The cells in Columns I, K, and M contain vlookup formulas. I have tried the code (shown below), but it is copying the formulas and not the values returned by those formulas. The vlookup formulas are in rows 2 through 201 in each column, but not all of them will have values to return.

How do I get the values to copy into Column A of the last worksheet?

```
Sub Create_Email_Distro()
'
    ' The following is a list of all the Source worksheets

    Dim PTASK_Template As Workbook ' source WorkBook
        Set PTASK_Template = Workbooks("BCRS Unassigned Tasks Template.xlsm")
    Dim PTASK As Worksheet
        Set PTASK = PTASK_Template.Sheets("BCRS Unassigned Tasks")
    Dim EDLd As Worksheet
        Set EDLd = PTASK_Template.Sheets("Email Distro")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    ' Copy WGM email addresses to Email Distro sheet

    Dim LRWGM As Long
    LRWGM = PTASK.Range("K" & PTASK.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim EDLRowW As Long
    EDLRowW = EDLd.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' DestinationRow
    PTASK.Range("K2:K" & LRWGM).Copy EDLd.Range("A" & EDLRowW)

    ' Copy SWGM emaill addresses to Email Distro sheet

    Dim LRSWGM As Long
    LRSWGM = PTASK.Range("M" & PTASK.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim EDLRowS As Long
    EDLRowS = EDLd.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' DestinationRow
    PTASK.Range("M2:M" & LRSWGM).Copy EDLd.Range("A" & EDLRowS)

    ' Copy AGD emaill addresses to Email Distro sheet

    Dim LRAGD As Long
    LRAGD = PTASK.Range("I" & PTASK.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim EDLRowA As Long
    EDLRowA = EDLd.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' DestinationRow
    PTASK.Range("I2:I" & LRAGD).Copy EDLd.Range("A" & EDLRowA)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

I have looked at several questions on here that are similar, but I am unable to locate one that is copying from a dynamic range and stacking the data from the 3 columns into one.

Example: [image]

Comment: the `.Copy` command copies the cell contents directly, meaning formulas or values or formats or whatever is in the cell as is. Change `PTASK.Range("M2:M" & LRSWGM).Copy EDLd.Range("A" & EDLRowS)` to `PTASK.Range("M2:M" & LRSWGM).Copy | EDLd.Range("A" & EDLRowS).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` *(pipe indicates new line)* ... follow suit for other lines.

Comment: Or you could avoid the clipboard altogether `EDLd.Range("A" & EDLRowS).resize(LRSWGM - 1,).Value = PTASK.Range("M2:M" & LRSWGM).Value`

Comment: Thank you both. @ScottCraner Just for better understanding, what does .resize do? I ask instead of looking it up so that if anyone else reads this post, they will also learn (if they don't already know).

Comment: Range.Resize does just that it re-sizes the range.  So in this case it takes a single cell and enlarges the range the number rows so that each range is the same size.  For example `Range("A1").Resize(4,4).Address(0,0)` will return `A1:D4` and `Range("A1:A4").Resize(1,4).Address(0,0)` will also return `A1:D4`.

Comment: @ScottCraner Very cool. Thank you very much for taking the time to explain that. And as an FYI, I was able to apply your answer to the sub and it has worked perfectly.